# Difference between distance to a sphere and to its center

Tags: geometry, 3d, spheres

I have a set of 3D points and a sphere. All the points lay outside the sphere. I want to find the point that is most close to the sphere.

The distance between a point (P) and a sphere (S) is defined as follow:

```
Distance(P,S) = Min [EuclideanDistance(P, Sp)] : Sp in S
```

Is it enough to find the point P that is most close to the center of the sphere?
Are those two operations equals?

Once again, no point lays inside the sphere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right. If your points are outside the sphere, then the point closest to the sphere is the one which is closest to the center of the sphere.

Comment: Thank you very much. BTW, can we say that the real distance to the sphere is (the distance to its center - its radius) ?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Yes, that is correct. Being a sphere is fundamental here. If it was, say, an ellipsoid, this would not be true.